# Disable a control using FindControl

Tags: asp.net

I have a situation where I need to dynamically disable certain controls. I will not be knowing the type of control. I tried to use FindControl(""), but this does not have the "Enabled" property, it only has "Visible" property.

Kindly let me know how this can be done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled.aspx) property is only exposed by the [WebControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx) class and its descendants. You'll need to ensure the control returned by [FindControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) is a web control and cast it as such before disabling it:

```
WebControl webControl = FindControl("yourControlId") as WebControl;
if (webControl != null) {
    webControl.Enabled = false;
}
```